# Showing the error of lmfit-model center in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar, lmfit

I'm working with fitting of data with the python lmfit package. I am looking at several peaks and fitting them with a pseudo-Voigt + constant model. I then extract the center position of the fitted peak and compile about a hundred of these peak positions. The hundred positions are then plotted and fitted with a sine-wave model, also with lmfit.
My issue, is that I am not able to find the information I need to show the uncertainty of the peak positions extracted from the pseudo-Voigt fitting. In many similar questions, I encounter the eval_uncertainty function also included in the lmfit package, but I am not able to use this to extract the confidence intervals of the center position, only uncertainties in the amplitude and sigma value of the peak.

The ideal result would look like the following image:
[The ideal case I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMpCj.png)

And my current graph looks like this:
[Current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPUNA.png)

Obviously I need to switch from a scatter plot to an errorbar plot, but I do not have any error-intervals to work with at the moment.

The following is the most simple workable "mini"-case I could construct, while still including my original fit-models. My original data is around 100 datapoints instead of four, and the sine-wave in this smaller case is therefore not "smooth", but this should not affect the method of introduction of errorbars.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import PseudoVoigtModel, ConstantModel, SineModel

def Voigt_app(x,y,a,b):
    
    psvo_mod = PseudoVoigtModel(prefix='psvo_')
    pars = psvo_mod.guess(y,x=x)
    
    con_mod = ConstantModel(prefix='con_')
    pars = pars.update(con_mod.make_params(c = (y[0]+y[1])/2))
    
    mod = psvo_mod + con_mod

    out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
    
    details = out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25)
    
    return out, details

def Sin_app(x,y):
    sin_mod = SineModel(prefix='sin_')
    pars = sin_mod.guess(y,x=x)
    
    con_mod = ConstantModel(prefix='con_')
    pars = pars.update(con_mod.make_params(c = np.mean(y)))
    
    mod = sin_mod + con_mod

    out = mod.fit(y,pars,x=x)
    details = out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25)
                       
    return out, details

data = np.asarray(
      [[14407.0 , 26989.0 , 31026.0 , 31194.0 , 31302.0 , 91996.0 , 112250.0 , 112204.0 , 113431.0 , 75097.0 , 55942.0 , 55826.0 , 56181.0 , 28266.0 , 14687.0],
       [12842.0 , 13275.0 , 13581.0 , 13943.0 , 14914.0 , 20463.0 , 21132.0 , 21457.0 , 23308.0 , 32017.0 , 30808.0 , 30927.0 , 30337.0 , 21025.0 , 15216.0],
       [15770.0 , 17677.0 , 19008.0 , 20911.0 , 25958.0 , 27984.0 , 28164.0 , 31161.0 , 33517.0 , 29430.0 , 28673.0 , 32725.0 , 28495.0 , 24527.0 , 25173.0],
       [16299.0 , 20067.0 , 25102.0 , 34968.0 , 37757.0 , 44871.0 , 51347.0 , 60154.0 , 54985.0 , 53383.0 , 45776.0 , 40836.0 , 30816.0 , 27922.0 , 26066.0]])
a,b = 1932, 1947
centers = []

colors = ['red','black','green','blue']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(4):
    ax.scatter(np.arange(15),data[i,:],label=f'data {i}',color=colors[i])
    out, details = Voigt_app(x,data[i,:],a,b)
    ax.plot(out.best_fit,label=f'fit {i}',color=colors[i])
    centers.append(out.values['psvo_center'])
ax.set_title('Data points and pseudo-Voigt fits')
ax.legend()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.arange(4),centers,color='red',label='data')

out, details = Sin_app(np.arange(4),np.asarray(centers))
ax.plot(np.arange(4),out.best_fit,color='black',label='fit')
ax.set_title('Peak positions and sine-wave fit')
ax.legend()
```

From this I would like to switch out the scatter plot in the second graph with an errorbar plot with the confidence intervals of the pseudo-Voigt peak positions ("out.values['psvo_center']").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to extract not only the best-fit value for the 'psvo_center' parameter for each of your fits, but also the standard error for 'psvo_center', and then use those as the data for fitting to a sinusoidal oscillation.

If that is correct, I think that what you want to do is to save the `stderr` attribute, by changing you code to

```
centers = []
stderrs = []  # < new

colors = ['red','black','green','blue']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(4):
    ax.scatter(np.arange(15),data[i,:],label=f'data {i}',color=colors[i])
    out, details = Voigt_app(np.arange(15), data[i,:], a, b)
    ax.plot(out.best_fit,label=f'fit {i}',color=colors[i])
    centers.append(out.params['psvo_center'].value)       # < new 
    stderrs.append(out.params['psvo_center'].stderr)      # < new
```

You can then use that to make and error-bar plot with

```
ax.errorbar(np.arange(4), centers, stderrs, color='red',label='data')
```

You might also want to use those `stderrs` to weight the fit to the sinusoidal function, perhaps modifying your `Sin_App` to be

```
def Sin_app(x, y, dely):       # < new
    sin_mod = SineModel(prefix='sin_')
    pars = sin_mod.guess(y,x=x)

    con_mod = ConstantModel(prefix='con_')
    pars = pars.update(con_mod.make_params(c = np.mean(y)))

    mod = sin_mod + con_mod

    out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x, weights=1./dely)    # < new
    details = out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25)
    return out, details
```

and calling that with

```
out, details = Sin_app(np.arange(4), np.asarray(centers), np.asarray(stderrs))
```

for the 4 example datasets you give, the variation in the standard-error isn't very big, so it does not make a big difference.  But as you add more datasets, it might become more important.  You might want to add a check that `stderr` is valid (like, not `None` and not `0`) before using this "in production".

For "one more thing", you might also want to calculate the predicted uncertainty in the sinusoidal function and plot that range too.   Your example has 4 variables for the sinusoidal fit and only 4 values, which results for this case in a near-perfect fit with absurdly small uncertainties on the fitted sine function. So to illustrate the approach, I fix the `con_c` parameter in the fit below.  If fitting the results of more than 4 peak profiles, that should not be necessary.  But, for illustration,
changing your `Sin_app` to be

```
def Sin_app(x, y, dely):
    sin_mod = SineModel(prefix='sin_')
    pars = sin_mod.guess(y,x=x)

    con_mod = ConstantModel(prefix='con_')
    pars = pars.update(con_mod.make_params(c = np.mean(y)))

    pars['con_c'].vary = False  # needed with only 4 (x,y) values

    mod = sin_mod + con_mod

    out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x, weights=1./dely)
    details = out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25)

    delta_fit = out.eval_uncertainty(sigma=1)   # < new
    return out, details, delta_fit
```

and then plotting the results of using that with

```
out, details, delta_fit = Sin_app(np.arange(4), np.asarray(centers), np.asarray(stderrs))

ax.plot(np.arange(4),out.best_fit, 'o', color='black',label='fit')

ax.fill_between(np.arange(4), 
                out.best_fit-delta_fit, out.best_fit+delta_fit,
                color="#D7D7D7")

ax.set_title('Peak positions and sine-wave fit')
ax.legend()
```

This leads to the final plot of:

[image: plot of final fit of peak centers to sinusoidal function]

showing the "data" for the peak centers with error bars, the fitted values, and the 1-sigma range of the fit.

Comment: Thank you! This worked excellently, I was hoping to be able to refrain from using the conf_interval function since this adds so much time to the process and this was the perfect way to do just that. 
As you mentioned, I encountered the None/0 issue as soon as i used my actual dataset. Right now I just set the value to an arbitrary low one as a temporary workaround, is there a standard procedure for avoiding this that's used? Or is the dataset the issue in this case?

Comment: After looking at this more I realize that the None-parameter is an issue of the data being too unlike a peak to be able to fit a peak at all, rather than a very good fit, so setting it to an arbitrary low number is quite the opposite of appropriate. Will look into it further, thank you for the help.

Comment: I would probably suggest first flagging and ignoring fits with stderr of None of 0 (or not available.  (another hint: you could test `result.errorbars` to see if uncertainties were calculated for a fit).  If it is just a few percent of the fits, you can probably just toss those out as "bad data/fits".  Then again, looking into why things sometimes go wrong can be very illuminating and sometimes (rarely, but not never) becomes more interesting than the initial task or the result you were trying to see.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could modify your Voigt_app function to do that:

```
def Voigt_app(x,y,a,b):
    
    psvo_mod = PseudoVoigtModel(prefix='psvo_')
    pars = psvo_mod.guess(y,x=x)
    
    con_mod = ConstantModel(prefix='con_')
    pars = pars.update(con_mod.make_params(c = (y[0]+y[1])/2))
    
    mod = psvo_mod + con_mod

    out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
    
    # Calculate the confidence interval for the fitted parameters
    ci = lmfit.conf_interval(out, out)
    print(lmfit.printfuncs.report_ci(ci))

    # Extract the uncertainty for 'psvo_center'
    center_err = (ci['psvo_center'][2][1] - ci['psvo_center'][1][1])/2

    details = out.fit_report(min_correl=0.25)
    
    return out, details, center_err
```

You can then use these uncertainties when plotting the error bars:

```
center_errs = []
for i in range(4):
    out, details, center_err = Voigt_app(x, data[i,:], a, b)
    # ...
    center_errs.append(center_err)

# ...

ax.errorbar(np.arange(4), centers, yerr=center_errs, fmt='o', color='red', label='data')
```

Comment: You could explicitly calculate the confidence intervals like this, but that is likely to be overkill if you want the 1-sigma uncertainty in the `psvo_center` parameter.   By default, for fits that can determine uncertainties in parameter values, the attribute `out.params['psvo_center'].stderr` will already have the estimated 1-sigma uncertainty, and is much faster than using `conf_intervals` -- which requires Parameters to have a `stderr` attribute to do a much slower search of confidence levels for each Parameter.